# VBA: Outlook Mailbox Folder, Count Keywords in Subject & Body and Export to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I will preface this by stating that I have no VBA knowledge, I can sort of read it but I certainly can't write it. I have also spent a good amount of time looking for previously answered questions that will provide me with a solution but have not found anything similar enough for me to adapt it with my limited knowledge.

What I am trying to do is write a VBA script that will read the subject of all emails in an Outlook folder, count predefined keywords and write the result to separate cells in an Excel spreadsheet. Additionally, read the body and copy an entire sentence that appears after a phrase to a cell in Excel.

These emails have a fixed format:
**Subject**: 
[keyword, three possibilities] [keyword, three possibilities] ["!" or "?" or nothing]
**Body**:
Search Engine: [text to copy, single word]
Keyword: [text to copy, a single sentence on one continuous line]

Below is code I believe to be relevant to what I'm trying to do but can't piece together into a single script. For reading a single, selected email in Outlook and writing the subject to separate Excel cells based on a pre-defined pattern:

```
Option Explicit
 Private Const xlUp As Long = -4162

 Sub CopyToExcel()
 Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim vText, vText2, vText3 As Variant
 Dim sText As String
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath As String
 Dim Reg1 As Object
 Dim M1 As Object
 Dim M As Object

enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\Tally.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
     Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection()

    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     rCount = rCount + 1

     sText = olItem.Subject

     Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    ' \s* = invisible spaces
    ' \d* = match digits
    ' \w* = match alphanumeric

    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "((\w*)\s*(\w*)\s*(\w*))"
    End With
    If Reg1.test(sText) Then

' each "(\w*)" and the "(\d)" are assigned a vText variable
        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(sText)
        For Each M In M1
           vText = Trim(M.SubMatches(1))
           vText2 = Trim(M.SubMatches(2))
           vText3 = Trim(M.SubMatches(3))
        Next
    End If

  xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = vText
  xlSheet.Range("c" & rCount) = vText2
  xlSheet.Range("d" & rCount) = vText3

     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
     Set M = Nothing
     Set M1 = Nothing
     Set Reg1 = Nothing
     Set xlApp = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
 End Sub
```

A script that takes the date of an email and tallies the number of time it occurs:

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

For Each objItem in colItems
    strDate = FormatDateTime(objItem.SentOn, vbShortDate)
    If objDictionary.Exists(strOnline) Then
        objDictionary.Item(strOnline) = objDictionary.Item(strOnline) + 1
    Else
        objDictionary.Add strOnline, "1"
    End If
Next

colKeys = objDictionary.Keys

For Each strKey in colKeys
    Wscript.Echo strKey, objDictionary.Item(strKey)
Next
```

And a simple If statement, if the subject has this, then do this(?):

```
Dim strSubject As String
strSubject = Item.Subject
If strSubject Like "*example1*" or strSubject Like "*example2*" Then
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated as this is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You've got most of the pieces here, yes. But you'll have some difficulty. This is what I can whip up in a few minutes and without testing. SOme of this code appears to be written in Excel (the first code), whereas the second function you have looks like native Outlook VBA.

Either function can (relatively easily) be ported to the other application (which I've tried to do, assuming it's preferable to run this code *from* Excel VBA as a generally easier-to-work-with interface), but I make no guarnatees :)

Here's the general idea, and rough code:

- Use your second script, the one which loops over all emails, as the main script.
- Call the first script from within the loop, modifying it as needed with the logic you need and also to avoid re-opening the file every time.

Note: I am using late-binding on the Outlook objects so that this function can hopefully be called from Excel VBA without requiring reference to the outlook library. Also this code is not tested so make sure all variables are properly declared and typed.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main()
    Dim colItems as Object
    Dim objItem as Object      
    Dim objOutlook as Object   'Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace as Object 
    Dim objFolder as Object    'Outlook.Folder
    Dim objDictionary as Object  'Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim strSubject As String

    Const olFolderInbox = 6

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each objItem in colItems
        '## Get the subject
        strSubject = objItem.Subject

        '## Check for the conditions:
        If strSubject Like "*example1*" or strSubject Like "*example2*" Then
            Call WriteToExcel(objOutlook, objItem, "C:\path\to\your\file.xlsx")  '## MODIFY FILE PATH!
        End If
    Next

Next
End Sub

 Sub WriteToExcel(objItem As Object, $strPath)
 Dim olItem As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim sText As String
 Dim rCount As Long
 Dim txt as String

     Set xlApp = Application  'Assumes you're running this from EXCEL
     'Check if the workbook already open
     For each xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks
        If xlWB.FullName = strPath Then Exit For
     Next
     If xlWB Is Nothing Then Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     rCount = rCount + 1

     sText = objItem.Subject
     '## Prints the subject in Column B
     xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = sText

     '##### HERE IS WHERE YOU NEED TO COUNT YOUR KEYWORDS####
     '#######################################################
     '#######################################################
     '#######################################################
     txt = olItm.Body 



     '## Omitting lines that close Excel app & Workbook, etc.

     Set xlApp = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: As a note, I can run the first code of the OP in Outlook VBA. If I understand correctly, the whole thing is intended to be run in Excel VBA? When I copy, modify and run your code in Excel VBA, `Sub Main()` errors with `Sub or Function not defined` I don't understand why. How is the Outlook Mailbox Folder defined? In the second half of your code, `Set olItem = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection()` remains, which means the code applies to a selected mail item, does it not? At `Here is where you need to count your keywords` how am I doing this exactly? Thank you so far.

Comment: Yes, all the code should exist in an Excel module. I made a change to fix the error in second function. If there is still an error in Main function, you need to indicate what line is raising the "not defined" error.  As for counting words, *google it*. Otherwise, contact me offline and maybe we can negotiate something, but I'm not really in a position to hold your hand and teach you everything there is to know about VBA.